# What is the best way to cancel 3rd interview with company about to make offer?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, job-offer

I have a gig that is 100% commission (sales) but lots of freedom and ability to basically do as I please, just get deals done. Interviewed at another gig - in totally different industry - seeking more "stability" and better benefits.

Current position has now offered some base along with bump up in commish % - they don't want me to leave. Have 3rd interview upcoming but think I should definitely cancel and let them end the process. What is best way to do that? And what do HR people prefer...email or phone?

*Oh yeah...my wife currently works at the company I am going to bow out from.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site Sizzle. I thought we had a general question on this topic but can't find it at the moment. But while I couldn't find an existing question on how to bow out of the interview process when you've made up your mind, I did find what seems to be almost an exact duplicate for your situation: [How to gracefully decline a job interview when a family member works for the company?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18479). The main difference is that you're further in the process and won't be using "working with family" as your reason for declining. (Not voted as a dupe.)

Comment: I would simply be honest, if you are certain you aren't interested in pursuing the position any further you are doing them a favor. Explaining that you received a bump from your current company will give some context to your decision.

Comment: @Lilienthal and Bluebird Thanks for the input.Honesty is definitely the way I will go.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to overthink this.

If you are sure that you no longer want to pursue this opportunity, contact the company and say exactly that. Use whichever form of communication you've been using regularly up to now. They will probably ask why, and you can tell them as much or as little as you feel comfortable with. probably best to tell them "my circumstances have changed", so they don't think it was something they did that drove you away.

I would say that it may not be a good idea to reject the other company without having heard what they can offer. There's no harm in going to the third interview, even if you are 99% sure that you want to stay where you are. (And "I think I should definitely cancel" sounds like you are not quite sure). Maybe they will offer you double your pay. You never know unless you ask. And in the worst case it's good interview experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My concern with going to a 3rd interview and then getting an offer that I turn down - yes, they may double my pay but that is unlikely - is that I don't want it to reflect poorly on my wife and give her any problems.

Comment: How would this reflect poorly on your wife?

Comment: I should have said "have any negative effect" as opposed to "reflect poorly." people are people...obviously you'd think it should have no bearing but you never know.

Comment: @Sizzle  If the people there for some reason think negatively of you or your wife for turning down an offer, they might also think negatively of you bowing out at the last moment. All you can do is be to be respectful and professional in whatever action you take (whether you hear their offer or not). If they think badly about you for whatever reason, I don't see how you can prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up going with:

> Good morning. I am glad you had a chance to speak with XXX. My meeting
>   with YYY was moved to 12pm today. In the interest of not wasting your
>   time I need to let you know that yesterday the owner of my current
>   firm made an offer to provide me with a monthly base salary + a bump
>   up in commission percentage, to keep me on. After discussion with my
>   family I slept on the offer and have decided today to accept it. The
>   financial benefits, vote of confidence from management and significant
>   milestone  incentives are best for me and my family at the moment.
>
> I want to thank you for your time and effort. CCC has nothing but
>   fantastic things to say about XYZ, inc. - the workplace culture, the
>   people and the clients. I will surely continue to promote the company
>   and services when speaking with people about XYZ, inc locally, as I
>   often do.
>
> Would you like me to contact YYY or would it be best for you to notify
>   her? Please advise.

Comment: "Wasting your time" probably not the best phrase.

Comment: yeah, probably.

Comment: I think too much information.  "Yesterday I was offered a raise at my current company and have decided to stay."

Comment: @Lilienthal What is the edit you made? I am not seeing it.

Comment: @Sizzle You can click on the "[edited yesterday](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/58274/revisions)" hyperlink above my portrait to view the revisions. I just converted your test to use the block quote markup. It's more obvious if you select "side-by-side markdown" in the view.

Comment: @lilienthal gotcha. thx.